# Can I create a constructor for a @Component class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

This is my component class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default-values")
public class DefaultConfig {

    private Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
    private WHO whoHdr;

    DefaultConfig() {

        countries.put("966 - Saudi Arabia", "966");
        countries.put("965 - Kuwait", "965");        
    }

}
```

Under my application.yaml file, I've configured values to be set for 'WHO' fields.

But, since I have defined DefaultConfig class as a **@Component**, can I create a constructor separately for creating a HashMap object? Because I cannot create an instance of DefaultConfig using New keyword if I want to inject this into another class.

Is there any better way to have this countries object instead of putting them in a default constructor which should be ready for Autowiring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

You don't need to put `@Component` on classes marked as `@ConfigurationProperties` apart of the fact that spring can map the configuration data into these classes, they are regular spring beans and therefore can be injected into other classes.

You do need however "map" this configuration properties by `@EnableConfigurationProperties(DefaultConfig.class)` on one of your Configuration classes (or even `@SpringBootApplication` which is also a configuration class).

Now Since `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class is a spring bean, you can use `@PostConstruct` on it to initialize the map:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "default-values")
public class DefaultConfig {

    private Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
    private WHO whoHdr;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {

        countries.put("966 - Saudi Arabia", "966");
        countries.put("965 - Kuwait", "965");        

    }  

    //setter/getter for WHO property 

}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DefaultConfig.class)
class SomeConfiguration {

}
```

Its worth to mention that in Spring boot 2.2 ConfigurationProperties classes can be immutable, so you won't need getter/setter.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is there anyway, to inject a class into a non-spring bean class

Comment: In general case, no, because its spring can inject A into class B only if it manages them both. There are workarounds probably depending on your concrete situation, but in any case consider asking another question

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this "You do need however "map" this configuration properties by @EnableConfigurationProperties(DefaultConfig.class) on one of your Configuration classes (or even @SpringBootApplication which is also a configuration class)."... it would be helpfult if you could elaborte!

Comment: I mean you do mention it could be injected as a bean to other class, but the later statement is bit confusing

Answer (score 11):

> @PostConstruct

is an annotation for bean component methods which executes before the bean is registered to the context. You can initialize defaults / constants values in this method.

Refer below link for more information:

https://www.journaldev.com/21206/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Comment: `before the bean is ready for injecting to your application` You might want to reword this to *before the bean is registered to the context*, as an inexperienced user might understand it to mean that it is called before DI has been applied to the bean (which is not the case).